# How to compare strings with parenthesis, comma and slashes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

how do I compare/filter string in javascript that contains parenthesis, comma, etc. I want to compare the strings as is.

Variables defined:

```
   src = "qy(abc,tii,2,01/15/2014,pcurve_test)";
   fav = "qy(abc,tii,2,01/15/2014,pcurve_test)";

        var pattern = "";
        var find = '/';
        var re = new RegExp(find,'g');
        pattern = new RegExp('^' + src + '$', 'i');
        var favStr = fav.replace(re,'\\/');
        var ismatch = favStr.toLowerCase().trim().match(pattern);
```

The above code always returns false.

Comment: Are you escaping those special characters in your filtering? `match()` uses RegEx.

Also post the rest of the code. There isn't enough to tell what's wrong.

Comment: no I want to compare them as is. And the string pattern will not always the same. Some may have '/' some may no, some may have additional character.

Answer (score 0):

`pattern` is a string, but it looks like you want it to be a regular expression based on your concatenation statement.  I don't know where any of your variables are defined, but you could give this a shot:

```
var favs = favList.filter(function (fav) {
    pattern = new RegExp('^' + src + '$', 'i');
    return fav.expression.val().trim().match(pattern);
});
```

[Regular Expression Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: still not working, could it be because fav is still a string with parenthesis and slashes?

Comment: You don't have enough code here.  Can you provide a link or post the problem code to JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XNJxT/3158/  - not sure what is the issue here. Is it the braces?